# Build action url without app part in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is there any way to get in code URL to action but without application name part?

I need to invoke `Url.Action("Create", "Home")` and get */home/Create* but not */AppName/home/Create*.

Map route is default: {controller}/{action}/{id}

Application is published to 'AppName' folder on server and `Url.Action("Create", "Home")` returns */AppName/home/Create*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative()` helper. For example:

```
// returns /AppName/Home/Create.
var withAppNameUrl = Url.Action("Create", "Home");

// returns ~/Home/Create
var relativeToAppUrl = VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(withAppNameUrl);
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.toapprelative%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).